# Nhibernate/Domain Objects generate test objects with random data from factory

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nhibernate, domain-driven-design

We are doing some DDD at work and I am trying to find a good utility for generating Domain Objects with random data, or predefined data, and populating dependent objects.

Example Usage:

```
var user = DDDObjectFactory.CreateUser();
user.Name = "TestUser";
```

In our world, a user can not exist without a organization, so if there is no organization we need to create on of those too.

For a specific test, i may not care about any property other than the username, so that is the only one that I specify real data for, all others should have random data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or [NBuilder](http://nbuilder.org/)

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at [AutoFixture](http://autofixture.codeplex.com/).